# How to force working copy to be committed in SVN after revert

Tags: svn

I had to reverted my SVN protected code to an earlier version, which I then modified heavily.  I want to commit the modified version to the SVN, but when I try to commit, the SVN tells me that I have to update first. Which I do not want to do.

Is it possible to specify that my local version (the working copy) is the new current correct version, without an update from the SVN?

Comment: You have to use Subversion terms correctly, because you **not reverted** (AFAICS), but updated to older (non-head) revision your WC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be `svn up --accept mine-full`

Comment: That'll work. You're basically merging your changes back into the current revision.

Comment: I tried this. It seems that the `accept mine` indeed tells svn to keep your part of the work, but in case some directories were renamed or deleted they will reappear after this command, so you'll have to do some manual cleanup. But it did simplify the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't commit changes except at the `HEAD` of the trunk or branches. This is try for all version control systems. Otherwise, people will be overwriting changes they wanted to keep.

There are two things you can do:

1. Go a head and update to the latest revision. Subversion won't overwrite your changes, but instead will simply update where it can. There might be some conflicts. It all depends how old the code you've modified is. For example, we're currently at revision 12,001, and I checked out revision 11,980 because that's what was on our server, and I was debugging it. I fixed a few minor issues in two files. Updating to the most recent revision will update all files, even the files I worked on, but not the areas of those files I was working on. Very likely, this is really what i want to do. (Of course, thoroughly test once you update!).
2. Create a new branch based upon your revision. Subversion can do this in a millisecond. Then, commit your changes on that new branch.

Let's assume again, I checked out revision 11,980 and the latest revision was 12,0001:

```
$ svn co -r 11980 http://path/to/my/project workdir
$ cd workdir
...a bunch of changes
$ svn commit -m"My changes"
SVN Error: you need to update first...
$ svn copy -r11900 http://path/to/my/project@11900 http://path/to/branches/my_branch/project
```

Now, I have the *base* of what I was working on as a branch. Now, I'm going to switch to that branch:

```
$ svn switch http://path/to/branches/my_branch/project
```

My working directory is on the new branch which was based upon the old revision I was working on. All of my changes are untouched with the switch. I can now commit my changes without any problems.

```
$ svn commit -m"My changes"
$ It worked!
```

Now, if I want, I can merge my changes back to the original project:

```
$ svn co http://path/to/my/project workdir2
$ cd workdir2
$ svn merge http://path/to/branches/my_branch/project
```

Answer (score 0):

1) take the backup of your final code base some where else in your hard disk.
2) take update
3) delete all from SVN
4) Copy paste all code base from backup drive
5) Commit

OR

You can perform Cleanup if it helps, that i don't think so...

Comment: I did try this (the copy and the clean up), but svn seems to do the right thing and keep track of the dates.